# Comments are showing Anonymous commenter name

Tags: comments

I am working on comments module. I have requirement to display comments in chronological order, for this I have used [Comment goodness](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_goodness) module and suddenly comments started getting posted anonymously. Even after I removed this module Anonymous name showing on each comment and even this is authenticated user. I have disabled "User verification status in comments" in appearance. But still it is showing Anonymous.

Comment: Are you uninstall that module or just disabled.

Comment: I have disabled, and removed it from contrib module folder also.

Comment: Please check in comment table that user ID is inserted or not for comment.

Comment: Yes I have checked. It is inserting uid 0 for every comment even commenter is authenticated user.

Comment: I think you need to debug the code why user id is not inserting.